# How to disable an internal settings page/tab of a browser from opening?

Tags: html, browser, youtube

As context, I would say that I am suffering from a self diagnosed Youtube Addiction. For which, I decided to use Blocksite extension to block the said website which worked pretty well. But after sometime, I came across a page called brave://extensions which is part of the internal settings of the Brave browser. Due to which, my addiction resurfaced stronger than before as I could now toggle the blocksite extension off through this page. I have tried to block this webpage as well through the extension but it doesn't work on this page as it said the url is incorrect since it is not exactly a url but internal settings tab of the browser. Is there a way I can block this page and other internal tabs from opening? Please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [channel blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/channel-blocker/nfkmalbckemmklibjddenhnofgnfcdfp?hl=en) and [unhook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unhook-remove-youtube-rec/khncfooichmfjbepaaaebmommgaepoid?hl=en) extensions to get rid of unwanted content on youtube.

With the first one, you basically block youtube channels that come to the search result all the time. And with the hook, you have many options. You are not given video suggestions anymore.